# Try to use TZDB ... how to convert in delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

How to convert this code in delphi7...

```
 procedure Tform1.button1.click(sender: tobject);  
 var
   LTZID: string;
 begin
  // Write each time zone ID on the console 
  for LTZID in TBundledTimeZone.KnownTimeZones(true) do
  WriteLn(LTZID);
end;
```

Thank you...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
procedure Tform1.button1.click(sender: tobject);
 var
   i: Integer;
 begin
  // Write each time zone ID on the console
  for i := Low(TBundledTimeZone.KnownTimeZones(true))
      to High(TBundledTimeZone.KnownTimeZones(true)) do
    WriteLn(TBundledTimeZone.KnownTimeZones(true)[i]);
end;
```

or, a bit optimized:

```
procedure Tform1.button1.click(sender: tobject);
 var
   KnownTimeZones: TStringDynArray;
   i: Integer;
 begin
  // Write each time zone ID on the console
  KnownTimeZones := TBundledTimeZone.KnownTimeZones(true);
  for i := Low(KnownTimeZones) to High(KnownTimeZones) do
    WriteLn(KnownTimeZones[i]);
end;
```